# Matching array of objects containing an Object using Aggregration framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is how data is in my mongodb database.

```
_id:ObjectId('5c38e514b88edd0ef236c3f7'),
rooms:[
 {
   info:{
      name:'John',
      age:'23'
   }
 },
 {
   info:{
      name:'Mary',
      age:'15'
  }
 }
]
```

Using aggregation framework, I want to match then 'name' field which is inside the info object of which is in the rooms array. How do I achieve this?

What I have tried so far:

```
    Hotel.aggregate([
        {$match: {
                 '_id':mongoose.Types.ObjectId(lodgeId), 
                 'rooms.info.name':'John'}}
   )]
```

This gives me ALL ROOMS instead of matching the one with name John.

How do I get only the matched row?

Comment: try replacing 'rooms.info.name':'John' with 'rooms.info.name': {$eq: ['John']}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you unwind the rooms array before the match:

```
Hotel.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$rooms"},
    {$match: {
             '_id':mongoose.Types.ObjectId(lodgeId), 
             'rooms.info.name':'John'}}
)]
```

You should get a document with only the rooms that have the name John.

[Unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) turns an array field into a new document for each item in the array.